# Design issue using document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications

I am learning how to create a simple CRUD Node Express Web Application using APIs.

When my index.js page loads I have a default html table which displays a record of data populated within the Function:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/getQuestion/+ID)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => loadHTML(data['data']));
    
});
```

Inside this function I made a Get API call to return the data which populates the table with a record stored in my Database.

I run into a problem when I want to update this table with the next record. When I get the next record, I increment my ID by 1.
But in order to display the new record into the table, I have to also perform a location.reload() to refresh the content within the table with the new data; This in turn clears out my ID indexes.

My questions are:

1. Where is the correct place within a js file to display the table data for my html table. Does it make sense to put it in: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded function ?
2. If so, then every time this table data changes I have to call a page refresh. Is this correct?
3. Doing the page refresh clears out all my variables that are used to populate the parameters of my APIs

Where am I going wrong here.

Comment: It would help us help you if we could see what `loadHTML` looks like, what `id` you're referring to, and how the "next record" gets created and used.

Comment: It sounds like you should just dynamically update the HTML of the page rather than reload the entire page.  Perhaps you use an Ajax call also to get the next record.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Where is the correct place within a js file to display the table data for my html table. Does it make sense to put it in: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded function ?

Yes and no. `DOMContentLoaded` is almost never needed outside library development. Instead, to make your code run only after the page has been parsed and the DOM built, do one of these things:

1. Use a module rather than a script (`<script type="module" ...>`) **if** your target browsers support it; or
2. Use `defer` on your non-module `script` tag; or
3. Put your non-module `script` tag at the end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag

If you do any of those things, your page's DOM is ready to be manipulated by your code by the time your code runs and you could just do the `fetch` without wrapping it in an event. Using a module also has the benefit that your top-level variables aren't globals and module code is always in strict mode.

But doing it in a `DOMContentLoaded` handler is fine too.

> 2. If so, then every time this table data changes I have to call a page refresh. Is this correct?

There are other ways to change or add to the table data. You haven't shown `loadHTML`, but you can use `appendChild` on the `table` or `tbody` element, `insertAdjacentHTML`, `insertAdjacentText`, etc. More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

> 3. Doing the page refresh clears out all my variables that are used to populate the parameters of my APIs

Yes, refreshing the page completely resets the global environment and all nested environments, so everything on the page is refreshed.

---

Side note: There are two minor problems with the `fetch` code you've shown:

1. I'm afraid it's falling prey to the `fetch` API footgun. `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* error, not *HTTP* error. So a 404, 500, etc., doesn't reject the promise. You have to check for HTTP success explicitly (which is why I always use a wrapper function).
2. You're not handling errors.

To fix both:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/getQuestion/+ID)
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => loadHTML(data['data']))
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
});
```

Comment: thanks, am working through your suggestions. However I am still not clear about how your table manipulation can be used to solve my problem. To be more specific, I am creating a quiz and each page will contain one question with a multiple choice response. When the user submits response and navigates to next question, how to replace the question rendered in the HTML table with the next question retreived via the fetch. Am I supposed to remove all the rows in the table and then rebuild it ?